# Como remover o /home/ da URL de uma View especifica ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso criar uma View chamada `BancoDeImagens` mas preciso que a URL dela ao invés de ser:

- www.site.com/home/BancoDeImagens

Gostaria de remover o `/home/` e separar os nomes por `-` para que fique assim:

- www.site.com/banco-de-imagens

Não consigo criar uma view assim:

```
public ActionResult banco-de-imagens(){

}
```

Minha pergunta: É possível mapear uma View para que a URL dela fique como igual ao exemplo acima?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível sim, para isso altere o seu `RouteConfig`

Provavelmente lá terá o seguinte código:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Acima desse código adicione o seguinte:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
   name: "BancoImagens",
   url: "banco-de-imagens",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "BancoImagens", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Sua `action` dentro do `controller` **home**

```
public ActionResult BancoImagens(){

}
```

obs: É importante que as rotas customizadas fiquem acima da rota `default` pois ele irá "entrar" na primeira que "casar"

Comment: Perfeito ! eu ja tinha usado o mapeamento... mas não sei porque não me passou pela cabeça fazer isso hehe. Obrigado !

Comment: Acontece kkkkk eu estava fazendo 1 aqui, ai veio a pergunta xD